# Wordpress NinjaForms WPSMTP From Field not obeyed in email sent

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, smtp

I'm using NinjaForms and WP SMTP (not the pro version).

**ISSUE:** when setting the FROM field for Email & Actions the 'Advanced' section has a 'From' field allowing overwrite of the 'From Fields (Name and Email)' in emails. Using the variable options this has been set to

```
[ From Name: {field:first_name} {field:last_name} ]
```

The issue is that when an email is sent the 'From Name' reverts back to the WP SMTP setting value even though the 'Force From Name' setting in WP SMTP is 'Off'.

[image: WP SMTP settings]

[image: NinjaForms settings]

**Checklist:**

1. Review WP SMTP and see what values are set for From Email and From Name OK. Force 'From name' and 'From email' are "off"
2. Go to NinjaForms form and set a custom 'From Name' and 'From Email' in the Emails & Actions => Advanced section
3. Send myself a form submission

**Result: Email received. From Name is the WPSMTP value, From Email is the custom Ninja forms value.**

*NOTE 1: This issue only presented itself after an update of PHP from 7.2 to 8.2. Prior to this update both From Fields were correctly being applied.

NOTE 2: Ninja forms have spent hours on this and confirmed that the correct Name and Email are passed to the mailer plugin so they asked us to follow the breadcrumbs ourselves.*

Any recommendations or contact methods/bug submission process at WP SMTP would be appreciated.